# Check if code is called from Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services

I have a class library that is either called from a webservice, a service or a windows forms app.

For the windows forms application I want to show a yes / no messagebox for the webservice and the service I just want to assume yes.

I know I can refactor my code to use an abstraction layer, e.g.

```
var provider = new MessageBoxProvider(); // Or other implementation
var result = provider.QueryResult(...);
```

but besides that:

Is there a better way to check if code is called from a windows application? Currently I am doing

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms.Count > 0
```

Comment: I'm not sure there needs to be any ui logic in your library, is it possible to refactor it to just return a message and let the caller handle it?

Comment: This looks like an XY problem, and plenty of solutions exist to prevent you from needing to tie library code to a particular UI framework in the first place. Apart from the abstraction layer you could create an event or callback that the calling application can subscribe to.

Comment: See also [Work out the type of c# application a class contained in a DLL is being used by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563677/work-out-the-type-of-c-sharp-application-a-class-contained-in-a-dll-is-being-use), where all current answers also exists with more information on potential drawbacks and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I use `System.Environment.UserInteractive` for that kind of check.

If I'm not wrong, this return true for a windows application, and false for a windows service, web application and web service. (what about a Console Application? I should check)

I agree that you should work it out in a different way, as other have pointed out

Comment: It returns true for a console app, I forgot about this, sounds like a good way to go.

Comment: tks @TheLethalCoder. thinking more about it, it should not depend on the type of application I think, it depends on how it run within the OS. If you start a console application from a command prompt UserInteractive is true, but I suspect that if you start it as a window scheduled task it's false.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use dependency injection, where you pass an interface with the method to the class, so it can be tested in unit test also, and be set from the Windows Forms app without relying on Windows Forms stuff inside that class. I guess that's like your abstraction layer.

```
public interface IMessageHandler
{
    void SendMessage(string message);
}

public class WindowsFormsMessageHandler : IMessageHandler
{
    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
}

public class OuterClass
{
    private IMessageHandler _handler;

    public OuterClass(IMessageHandler handler)
    {
        if (handler == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("handler");

        _handler = handler;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _handler.SendMessage("Hello");
    }    
}
```

...

```
var testClassInWindowsForms = new OuterClass(new WindowsFormsMessageHandler());

test.DoSomething();
```

By doing this you can just change the behavior based on the implementation based on where you come from, and not rely on checks that are potentially not reliable.

Comment: What question is this answering? Where does dependency injection come into play?

Comment: Instead of having (unreliable) detection in your class, provide an interface where you send the message to.

Comment: I updated with a code sample! This prevents you from dragging windows forms stuff into your class, and keep it from relying on checks that might change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass a bool to the class library, such as:

```
new ClassLibrary(true);
```

For when it is a WinForms app.

Then have the constructor similar to the following

```
ClassLibrary(bool calledFromWinforms)
```

I know this isn't the nicest code but it makes things simple and doesn't overcomplicate them.

Comment: I'd argue it makes it more complicated, it means there is still a need for the library to reference winforms classes, and its unclear to the caller why it would make a difference if its called from winforms or not.

Comment: @Sayse Like I said not the nicest code, but a way to 'solve' the problem, and if you want to make it clearer could always change it to `bool showMessageBox`

Comment: Sure, but I don't think it solves the problem, it just pushes it over to somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be is to add a property to the class that sets itself when instantiated to and stores the type of environment its running in. Than the property can be used later to identify where it was called from.